# How do I draw a bevel effect?

Tags: image-processing, graphics, python-imaging-library, drawing

I'm trying to understand how create the photoshop bevel effect using opencv

**This is how the bevel effect looks like :**

[image: bevel example]

---

### How the Photoshop Bevel effect works

There are a lot of options to tweak this effect but the most two important ones are the depth and the size of the bevel:

- **Depth of the bevel :**

  [image: depth bevel]
- **Size of the bevel :**

  [image: size bevel]

---

### What I found

What I've discovered so far is that this effect is a kind of **Bump map** that defines how the object interacts with a specific lighting source. 
But I couldn't find any information on how we can generate a bump map for a specific object.

---

### My question

So my question is : Is it possible to create this effect using a bump map? 
If yes how could we generate a bump map programmatically  (Using OpenCV for example)

Comment: Why do you want to do this in a library used for *vision*?

Comment: I just want to create this effect (Algorithm) using any programming language/Framework.

Comment: you _can_ use OpenCV to _draw_ but it's not made for that. it's really bad at it. try PIL instead. -- ok so you need to start by learning about 3D graphics. not necessarily OpenGL but geometry, shading and lighting (flat shading, phong, ...). DO NOT go into "bumpmaps". that's advanced and completely unnecessary here, if not entirely irrelevant. -- to recreate _those_ pictures, you only need to draw polygons (triangles even) of flat color. you can trivially calculate their corner points.